# python - generate random trafic with normal law

Tags: python, probability

I'm looking to use the normal law to generate pseudo-random events.

What I would like is:

- I give entities an average of occurence and a standard deviation values. Each entities will in the long time generate an event every "average" value time.
- every hour, I check every entities, and based on their average, standard deviation and the normal law, I compute if they are triggering an event or not.

How would you do that in python? I've got no clue myself :(

Thanks

Comment: Please see [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` on the non-empty sets; steal the basic `and_` operation to do your intersection.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_

# Start with an empty set
a = set()
b = {1, 4, 8, 9}
c = {1, 5, 10, 15}
d = {1, 100, 200}
e = {1, 2, 3}

my_sets = [a, b, c, d, e]

print(reduce(and_, [q for q in my_sets if q]))
```

Output:

```
{1}
```